# Magento 2.2 : How to add google map

Tags: magento2.2

How to add google map contact us page form.phtml file in magento 2.2

please advance thanks for help.

Comment: have you tried my code ?

Comment: https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-ajax-add-to-cart/

Answer (score 1):

**app/design/frontend/vendor/your-theme/requirejs-config.js**

```
 var config={
  paths: {
    "jquery.googleapi": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My-Key"
  },
  shim: {
    'jquery.googleapi': {
      'deps': [
        'jquery'
      ]
    }
  },
  deps: [
    "js/google_init"
  ]
};
```

> My-Key : add Your key of google map

**app/design/frontend/vendor/your-theme/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceContainer name="content">
         <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
            <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info" />
         </block>
      </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Contact Map extension](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.ContactMap) on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Amasty Google Map Extension in Magento 2.2

Provide your customers with the clear details about the location of your business. Display the physical address on the 'Contact Us' page using the appealing Magento Google Map.

https://amasty.com/google-map-for-magento-2.html#screenshots